# fabric crashes in intelij

Tags: java, minecraft

all i did is setup the project and the mod id and that stuff and first time running i get this erorr

Exception in thread "main" org.spongepowered.asm.launch.MixinInitialisationError: Error initialising mixin config modid.mixins.json

at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.Config.create([Config.java:153](https://Config.java:153))

at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.Mixins.createConfiguration([Mixins.java:100](https://Mixins.java:100))

at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.Mixins.addConfiguration([Mixins.java:87](https://Mixins.java:87))

at net.fabricmc.loader.launch.common.FabricMixinBootstrap.addConfiguration([FabricMixinBootstrap.java:44](https://FabricMixinBootstrap.java:44))

at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach([Iterable.java:75](https://Iterable.java:75))

at net.fabricmc.loader.launch.common.FabricMixinBootstrap.init([FabricMixinBootstrap.java:83](https://FabricMixinBootstrap.java:83))

at net.fabricmc.loader.launch.knot.Knot.init([Knot.java:132](https://Knot.java:132))

at net.fabricmc.loader.launch.knot.KnotClient.main([KnotClient.java:28](https://KnotClient.java:28))

at net.fabricmc.devlaunchinjector.Main.main([Main.java:86](https://Main.java:86))
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The specified resource 'modid.mixins.json' was invalid or could not be read

at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.MixinConfig.create([MixinConfig.java:1090](https://MixinConfig.java:1090))

at org.spongepowered.asm.mixin.transformer.Config.create([Config.java:148](https://Config.java:148))

... 8 more

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to change `modid.mixins.json` in  your `fabric.mod.json`

Comment: can it be because i am using tlauncher